# Can't write to firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I can't write to firestore. It's working for Storage and Realtime Database, but not for firestore, can you suggest where the issue might be?

**firebase.js**

```
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";

const firebaseConfig = {
  ...
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const firestore = getFirestore(app);
```

**CheckoutForm.js**

```
import { collection, addDoc } from "firebase/firestore"; 
import { firestore } from "../../firebase";

export const CheckoutForm = async (uid) => {
  console.log("object 1")
  try {
    const docRef = await addDoc(collection(firestore, "documents"), {
      first: "Ada",
      last: "Lovelace",
      born: 1815
    });
    console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error("Error adding document: ", e);
  }
  console.log("object 2")
}
```

Here I call CheckoutForm.
**Home.js**

```
import { loadStripe } from "@stripe/stripe-js";
import { Elements } from "@stripe/react-stripe-js"

const PUBLIC_KEY = "pkey_test_stripe"

const stripeTestPromise = loadStripe(PUBLIC_KEY);

export default function Home() {
return (
  <Elements stripe={stripeTestPromise}>
   <div> 
    <button onClick={() => CheckoutForm(currUser.uid)}>
       Upgrade to premium!
    </button>
   </div>
  </Elements>
);
}
```

For some reason I don't get any response or error. Console written "object1", but after try/catch construction nothing runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the root of problem, there was title directly in firestore "Databases linking, you should unlink if you want use this", some king of that. So I have clicked and after all works.

Answer (score 0):

```
export const CheckoutForm = async (uid) => {
    console.log("object 1")
    try {
      const docRef = await addDoc(collection(firestore, "documents"), {
        first: "Ada",
        last: "Lovelace",
        born: 1815
      });
      console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error("Error adding document: ", e);
    }
    console.log("object 2")
  }
await CheckoutForm();
```

Comment: Hi! Unfortunately I can't write  **await CheckoutForm();** out of scope or in invoking place. In other, nothing has changed.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible code on how you call your `CheckoutForm`.

Comment: Yup, I added **Home.js**

Comment: I have recognised, that the problem is directly in **await addDoc()**, for some reason I can't get response or some connection with firestore, don't know why